# How to remove anything behind symbol each line but don't remove the text in front of each line

Tags: notepad++

The problem is that i want to delete Certain text after a symbol is presented in a line and then continue and do the same procedure in the next line.

For example:

```
Hello 1 | I want to Delete this 123
Hello 2 | I want to delete this 321
```

I want it to become

```
Hello 1
Hello 2
```

Tried the "Search for: |.*, replace with nothing." But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close. The pipe `|` is a special regex character which must be escaped. You can use `\|.*$`, which adds the `$` end-of-line anchor. Make sure "Search mode: regular expression" is enabled in NP++.